# multiplying binomials (second problem)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a problem:

$(5x + 3e^x)(15x^2+e^x)$

My answer is:

$75x^3+5xe^x+45x^2e^x+3e^{2x} $

is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost: You want $$(5x + 3e^x)(15x^2+e^x) = 75x^3+5xe^x+45x^2e^x+\color{blue}{\bf3}e^{2x}$$

You were just a missing coefficient of $\,3\,$before the factor $e^{2x}$.

Comment: For all I know, you may have obtained this answer, and perhaps simply made a "typo" when typing it into your question!

Comment: Thank You! yes it was a typo...sorry about that...

Comment: You're welcome: I thought that might have been the case, after posting my answer. I can't tell you how much editing of my posts that I have to do on the  because of typos I make!

Comment: Re: you're edit...Yes, it's correct!

Comment: Thank You for understanding...lol..by the way how did you do the 2x exponent in your post above?

Comment: `e^{2x}` = $e^{2x}.\;$ Just use curly brackets when the exponent is more than one character.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks for everything.....